# Find some expectation of two random variable given the joint distribution

Tags: expected-value, independence, conditional-expectation

I have the following joint distribution for the random variable (X,Y):

[image]

Now, I have to compute the following expectations:

1. $E(X|Y)$
2. $E(X+Y^2 | Y)$

Now, for the first point, the procedure was the following:

[image]

But I don't know how to do the second one. Intuitively maybe I can write something like:

> $E(X+Y^2 | Y) = E(X|Y) + E(Y^2 | Y)$

but I stopped here.

Edit 1: I forgot to specify that $x,y$ are positive.

Comment: This is not a valid joint distribution function.  You need to be clear about its domain of definition.  Presumably $y$ and $x$ must be positive -- but that's not the only possible choice.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's my fault, I've edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the distribution is valid, for which you need to clarify its support, you've already solved it:
$$\mathbb E[X+Y^2|Y]=\mathbb E[X|Y]+\mathbb E[Y^2|Y]=1+1/Y+Y^2$$
Because given $Y$, expected value of $Y^2$ is itself.